# Get "https:://registry-1.docker.io/v2/" http: server gave http response to https client

Tags: docker, daemon, httpserver, docker-container, docker-daemon

Im on the remote server, which is linux machine. I am trying to pull some base images like nginx, alpine. when I used docker pull nginx, it gives me this error(server gave https response to https client with this url:https:://registry-1.docker.io/v2/) I tried changing the daemon.json file by adding insecure registries with this url, but still i cant pull the images

Expecting image to be pulled

Comment: Docker Hub is not an insecure registry. Check your network for something interviewing the connections, like a proxy or DNS.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `daemon.json` file works for me.
My `daemon.json` like below.

`{ "insecure-registries":["registry-1.docker.io"], "live-restore": true }`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).